# Связанные selectы

Tags: javascript, select

Подскажите, как лучше реализовать такое.
Есть несколько свойств, например:

1. Животное (варианты значений: не выбрано, медведь, тигр, жираф).
2. Цвет (варианты значений: не выбрано, белый, бурый, полосатый, зеленый).
3. Тип (варианты: не выбрано, травоядный, всеядное, плотоядный).

По умолчанию не выбрано ни одно значение. Выбор можно начинать с любого селекта, при этом в остальных значения должны подстраиваться автоматом.
Какой существует алгоритм для решения данной задачи?

---

Входные данные: список всех свойств для селектов, значение всех свойств,
элементы

```
медведь, белый, плотоядный
медведь, бурый, всеядный
жираф, полосатый, травоядный
......
и т.д.
```

Логику вывода элементов, реализовал, в принципе ничего сложного, а вот с селектами не могу понять, как поступить.

**upd**. единственное, что пришло в голову это два цикла:

```
/*
newSelects - то из чего будем формировать selectBox
{
    PROPERTY_CODE:{
        VALUES = []
    },
    PROPERTY_CODE:{
        VALUES = []
    },
    PROPERTY_CODE:{
        VALUES = []
    },
}

selectsState - содержит текущие выбранные значения селектов
*/

/*
Первый цикл собирает все item, которые нам подходят в массив selectedItems
А так же добавляет значения для селектов, в которых не выбрано никакого значения
*/

/*
Первый цикл собирает все item, которые нам подходят в массив selectedItems
А так же добавляет значения для селектов, в которых не выбрано никакого значения
*/

$.each(items, function(index, item) {
    var valid = true;

    $.each(selectsState,function(propCode,propVal){
        if(propVal.length > 0 && item.PROPERTY_VALUES[propCode] != propVal){
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(valid){
        selectedItems.push(item);
        $.each(selectsState,function(propCode,val){
            if(val.length==0){
                newSelects[propCode].VALUES.push(item.PROPERTY_VALUES[propCode]);
            }
        });

    }
});

/*
Второй цикл проходит по всем селектам, у которых значения выбраны и формирует для каждого из выбранных селектов, свой массив значений
*/

    $.each(selectsState,function(propCode,propVal){
        if(propVal.length==0){
            return true;
        }
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var valid = true;

        $.each(selectsState,function(innerPropCode,innerPropVal){
            if(propCode==innerPropCode){
                return true;
            }

            if(innerPropVal.length > 0 && item.PROPERTY_VALUES[innerPropCode] != innerPropVal){
                valid = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if(valid){
            newSelects[propCode].VALUES.push(item.PROPERTY_VALUES[propCode]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: А в каком формате у Вас записаны данные для других `select`'ов. Вы бы реализовали подстановку значений для выбора(или что у Вас там должно быть) после изменения одного с `select`'ов или сделать кнопку для осуществления данного действия